# How does Objective-C's asynchronous request model work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've been playing with Objective-C the past couple of weeks and have a working app that performs an async HTTP Request to pull some data from Twitter.

I come from a web application background and have become use to how Javascript handles callbacks by passing a function that is called when an XHR request is done loading. As such, I find Objective-C's model of handling async requests with delegate objects and the perfomSelector method pretty darn cool.

```
[callbackObj performSelector:@selector(callbackMethod:) withObject:argObj];
```

So my question is, what is the design of Objective-C's async model and how does it work?

Comment: The example you gave isn't asynchronous. -performSelector:withObject: performs the selector on the receiver immediately. Have I misunderstood your point?

Comment: the example i gave just shows how callbacks are executed - one of the elements of the overall question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of "Cocoa Classic's" async behavior is / was implemented on top of `NSRunLoop`. Many of the more recent additions and updates to Cocoa are moving to [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).